# Haskell define return for Monad with function and Either

Tags: haskell, monads

how do i define a monad for such a datatype in Haskell? It is basically a salsa interpreter. And I cant figure out what should the return look like. It is making me crazy...

```
newtype Salsa a = Salsa {
    runSalsa :: Context -> Either String (a, Context, Animation)}

instance Monad Salsa where
    return a = Salsa $ ..........

instance Functor Salsa where
    fmap = liftM
instance Applicative Salsa where
    pure = return
    (<*>) = ap
```

http://ap-e2015.onlineta.org/assignments/assignment-1-salsa-interpreter.html

Comment: What is salsa? It would be helpful to provide a link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Help yourself with [typed holes](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.8.4/docs/html/users_guide/typed-holes.html): Write an underscore where you are stuck:

```
instance Monad Salsa where
    return a = Salsa $ _
```

and the compiler tells you it needs a function here

```
Found hole ‘_’
  with type: Context -> Either String (a, Context, Animation)
```

Now you can work your way with

```
instance Monad Salsa where
    return a = Salsa $ \x -> _
```

---

For `>>=`, do almost the same:

```
(Salsa s) >>= f = Salsa $ \x -> _
```

and the compiler outputs

```
Found hole ‘_’ with type: Either String (b, Context, Animation)
Relevant bindings include
  con :: Context
  f :: a -> Salsa b
  s :: Context -> Either String (a, Context, Animation)
```

So, `s` is function that requires a `Context`, but our `con` supplies one, put it together:

```
(Salsa s) >>= f = Salsa $ \con -> let s' = s con in _
...
  s' :: Either String (a, Context, Animation)
    (bound at Review.hs:12:43)
  f :: a -> Salsa b (bound at Review.hs:12:19)
```

So we need that `a` thing out of `s'` to supply it to `f`. Pattern match on `s'` (while renaming):

```
(Salsa salsaFunction1) >>= f = Salsa $ \context1 -> 
  let salsaResult1 = salsaFunction1 context1
   in case salsaResult1 of
        Left errorMsg                   -> Left errorMsg
        Right (a, context2, animation1) ->
           let Salsa salsaFunction2 = f a
               salsaResult2         = salsaFunction2 context2
            in _


  salsaFunction2 :: Context -> Either String (b, Context, Animation)
  animation1 :: Animation
  context2 :: Context
  a :: a
  salsaResult1 :: Either String (a, Context, Animation)
  context1 :: Context
  f :: a -> Salsa b 
  salsaFunction1 :: Context -> Either String (a, Context, Animation)
```

So, we have another `salsaFunction2`, and an unused `context2`. You already saw how to put this together: do another case analysis, in the `Right` case supply `context3`, the monadic result `b` and combine both animations to provide the final `Either String (b, Context, Animation)` that was seen again and again:

```
Found hole ‘_’ with type: Either String (b, Context, Animation)
```

Comment: `instance Monad Salsa where
    return a = Salsa $ \con -> Right (a, con, [] :: Animation)
    (Salsa function) >>= f = Salsa $ \con1 -> 
        let result = function con1 in 
        case result of
            Left errorMsg -> Left errorMsg
            Right (a, con2, anim) ->
                let Salsa function2 = f a
                    result2 = function2 con2
                in 
                case result2 of 
                    Left errorMsg -> Left errorMsg
                    anim3 = anim ++ anim2
                    Right (b, con3, anim2) -> Right (b,con3, anim3)`

Comment: Could you elaborate on that? I think i am close

Comment: `instance Monad Salsa where
    return a = Salsa $ \con -> Right (a, con, [] :: Animation)
    (Salsa function) >>= f = Salsa $ \con1 -> 
        let result = function con1 in 
        case result of
            Left errorMsg -> Left errorMsg
            Right (a, con2, anim) ->
                let Salsa function2 = f a
                    result2 = function2 con2
                in 
                case result2 of 
                    Left errorMsg -> Left errorMsg
                    Right (b, con3, anim2) -> Right (b,con3, mappend anim anim2)`

Comment: That newest one compiles. How can i make sure that it is correct?

Comment: The magic of haskell is: when it compiles, it usually is right. From what I see your solution looks good.

Answer (score 6):

You need a function which takes a `Context` so use a lambda `\con ->`.

You don't have anything that has failed so far so you can always succeed. `Right`.

`a` is provided by the call to `return`. `(a,`.

`Context` is provided by the call to the lambda. `con,`.

Now you have to decide on the animations to include, I would guess none. `[])`. (Note I don't remember offhand the exact syntax there but I think this is right).

Putting it all together you get:

```
return a = Salsa $ \con -> Right (a, con, [])
```

Now comes the complicated case where you have to handle bind (`>>=`).

Comment: I did this: 
`instance Monad Salsa where
    return a = Salsa $ \con -> (a, con, [] :: Animation)` 
but it says that 
`Couldn't match expected type `Either
                                    String (a, Context, Animation)'
                with actual type `(a, Context, Animation)'
    Relevant bindings include
      a :: a (bound at SalsaInterp.hs:33:12)
      return :: a -> Salsa a (bound at SalsaInterp.hs:33:5)
    In the expression: (a, con, [] :: Animation)
    In the second argument of `($)', namely
      `\ con -> (a, con, [] :: Animation)'
    In the expression:.....`

Comment: How can I show what to do in `Left` case and what in `Right`?

Comment: @Ezis All that is missing (for `return`, at least) is wrapping the tuple in `Right`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I don't know anything about Salsa, but after reading Guvante's answer foreshadowing the difficulty of implementing `>>=`, I thought it would be an interesting exercise. And since I don't know what Salsa's Context or Animation types are, I decided to just parameterize over them, which I think worked out fairly well: the type of Context can be totally opaque to us as implementors of `>>=`, and we just need `Animation` to be a monoid:

```
newtype Salsa ctx error anim a = Salsa {
    runSalsa :: ctx -> Either error (a, ctx, anim)
    }

instance Monoid anim => Monad (Salsa ctx error anim) where
    return x = Salsa $ \ctx -> return (x, ctx, mempty)
    (Salsa m) >>= f = Salsa m'
      where m' ctx = m ctx >>= handle
            handle (x, ctx, anims) = let (Salsa f') = f x
                                         merge (a, b, c) = (a, b, mappend anims c)
                                     in merge <$> f' ctx


instance Monoid anim => Functor (Salsa ctx error anim) where
    fmap = liftM
instance Monoid anim => Applicative (Salsa ctx error anim) where
    pure = return
    (<*>) = ap
```

This as general as I could figure how to make it, and I'm still not totally happy with the implementation of `handle`: it seems like there must be a better way to get the animation results combined than letting a function and then fmapping it, but I couldn't find anything prettier.

Incidentally I think it would be nicer to have a real data type for this `(a, Context, Animation)` group rather than just a tuple. Then you could, for example, give it a Functor instance and simplify the implementation of `handle`, removing the `merge` function and just writing

```
mappend anims <$> f' ctx
```

Comment: I don't think your implementation is ugly. At heart, this is State + Writer + Either, so it is not surprising that the plumbing gets a bit hairy.

Comment: I believe when @Guvante wrote "Now comes the complicated case" for `>>=` they were omitting the `>>=` part on purpose, so not to hand out the full solution to the assignment and make the OP work on it on their own.